# How can I select only the rows from a table with ids that don't exist in an inner join in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

I have the following table

```
postgres=# select * from joins_example;
 user_id | price  | id |          email           
---------+--------+----+--------------------------
       1 | $30.00 |    | 
       5 | $50.00 |    | 
       7 | $20.00 |    | 
         |        |  1 | hadil@example.com
         |        |  5 | saiid@example.com
         |        |  2 | fahir@example.com
       6 | $60.00 |  6 | oma@example.com
       8 | $40.00 |  8 | nasim@example.com
         |        |  8 | nasim.hassan@example.com
       9 | $40.00 |  9 | farah@example.com
       9 | $70.00 |    | 
      10 | $80.00 |    | majid@example.com
         |        | 10 | majid.seif@example.com
(13 rows)
```

A self inner join between `user_id` and `id` produces

```
postgres=# select * from joins_example as x inner join joins_example as y on x.user_id = y.id;
 user_id | price  | id |       email       | user_id | price  | id |          email           
---------+--------+----+-------------------+---------+--------+----+--------------------------
       1 | $30.00 |    |                   |         |        |  1 | hadil@example.com
       5 | $50.00 |    |                   |         |        |  5 | saiid@example.com
       6 | $60.00 |  6 | oma@example.com   |       6 | $60.00 |  6 | oma@example.com
       8 | $40.00 |  8 | nasim@example.com |         |        |  8 | nasim.hassan@example.com
       8 | $40.00 |  8 | nasim@example.com |       8 | $40.00 |  8 | nasim@example.com
       9 | $40.00 |  9 | farah@example.com |       9 | $40.00 |  9 | farah@example.com
       9 | $70.00 |    |                   |       9 | $40.00 |  9 | farah@example.com
      10 | $80.00 |    | majid@example.com |         |        | 10 | majid.seif@example.com
(8 rows)
```

What I want is either:

```
 user_id | price  | id |       email       | user_id | price  | id |          email           
---------+--------+----+-------------------+---------+--------+----+--------------------------
       7 | $50.00 |    |                   |         |        |    |
         |        |    |                   |         |        |  2 | fahir@example.com
```

or:

```
 user_id | price  | id |       email       | user_id | price  | id |          email           
---------+--------+----+-------------------+---------+--------+----+--------------------------
         |        |    |                   |       7 | $50.00 |    |
         |        |  2 | fahir@example.com |         |        |    |
```

Even

```
 user_id | price  | id |          email           
---------+--------+----+--------------------------
       5 | $50.00 |    | 
         |        |  2 | fahir@example.com
```

would be a good start.

Specifically I want to know how to select only the rows from `joins_example` with `user_id`s or `id`s that don't exist in the inner join.

Comment: Is it safe to assume, that ```user_id``` and ```id``` are equal in one row, if both are set? Why do you want one of the upper two outputs and not the last? There is no additional information, you just need more checks to determine where your values are

Comment: The additional information is which side of the cross product it would have come from had it been produced as part of a join. This is out of the scope of the question but I'm looking to union this with the inner join. Full joins contain the inner join as well as rows for the cross of both where each side is null. This is ok for joins which reference different tables but for self joins it creates a lot of rows that contain the same information as the rows that matched the search conditions. I want a fast, intuitive and non-lossy approach to self joins on highly heterogenous data.

Comment: You find the "side" information as well in the last output. You just need to lookup which of your 2 join fields is empty

Comment: Ah I see. Now I just need to encode this information in the format which is `union`able with the inner join.

Comment: I see now that you're right that there is no extra information as in the cross product both would appear on both sides. This means the rest of the columns can simply be null.

Comment: Yes.. If you really need this format (well, for a ```UNION``` you might), perhaps you can add a ```LEFT JOIN``` on ```joins_example``` with a contradiction as condition (so nothing is matched, but you get nulled columns of the correct data type).

Comment: `SELECT
  w.user_id,
  w.price,
  w.id,
  w.email,
  NULL AS user_id,
  NULL AS price,
  NULL AS id,
  NULL AS email
FROM joins_example AS w
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
  x.user_id
FROM joins_example AS x
INNER JOIN joins_example AS y
  ON x.user_id = y.id) AS z
  ON z.user_id = w.user_id
  OR z.user_id = w.id
WHERE z.user_id IS NULL
UNION
SELECT
  *
FROM joins_example a
INNER JOIN joins_example b
  ON a.user_id = b.id;`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM joins_example AS w 
LEFT JOIN (
    select x.user_id 
    from joins_example as x 
    inner join joins_example as y on x.user_id = y.id
) AS z ON z.user_id = w.user_id or z.user_id = w.id 
WHERE z.user_id IS NULL;
```

Is a good enough start i.e.

```
 user_id | price  | id |       email       | user_id 
---------+--------+----+-------------------+---------
       7 | $20.00 |    |                   |        
         |        |  2 | fahir@example.com |
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider an approach that uses correlated subqueries with `NOT EXISTS` conditions:

```
select * 
from joins_example as x 
where 
    ( 
        x.user_id is not null 
        and not exists (
            select 1 from joins_example y where  x.user_id = y.id
        )
    )
    or ( 
        x.id is not null 
        and not exists (
            select 1 from joins_example y where  x.id = y.user_id
        )
    )
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q1Snb8xx8kY5bLyMMkMtpP/0)**:

```
| user_id | price | id  | email             |
| ------- | ----- | --- | ----------------- |
| 7       | 20.00 |     |                   |
|         |       | 2   | fahir@example.com |
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM joins_example j
WHERE (j.user_id IS NULL AND j.id IS NULL)
    OR (j.user_id IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM joins_example j2 WHERE j2.id = j.user_id))
    OR (j.id IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM joins_example j2 WHERE j2.user_id = j.id));
```